# How to simplify modulo

Tags: math, numbers, modulo

I am trying to find the modulo of an expression. All I know is that

```
(a+b) mod N = ((a mod N) + (b mod N)) mod N
```

How do I use it to simplify the following modulo operation?

```
(a - 2*b + 1) mod N
```

There must be some way to simplify it by considering it as

```
(a - b - b + 1) mod N ?
```

**EDIT:**

I have stumbled upon the following property too:

```
ab mod N = ((a mod N) (b mod N)) mod N
```

Will this be helpful somehow?

Comment: really should be (b*-2 + a + 1) % n to avoid confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If: `(a+b) mod N = ((a mod N) + (b mod N)) mod N`

then:

```
(a - 2*b + 1) mod N = ((a mod N) - (b mod N) - (b mod N) + (1 mod N)) mod N
```

It is simpler with large values of a and b and a small value for N.

For example: a=85773, b = 77733340, N=5: 
which would you rather solve

```
(85773 - 77733340 - 77733340 + 1) mod 5
```

or

```
((85773 mod 5) - (77733340 mod 5) - (77733340 mod 5) + (1 mod 5)) mod 5
```

for the second one i get `(3 - 0 - 0 + 1) % 5 = 4`

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to simplify `(b*-2 + a + 1) % n` unfortunately.

Comment: Can it not be simplified by considering it as (a -b -b +1) mod N ?

Comment: Let `(a - 2*b + 1) mod N = (((a-2*b) mod N) + (1 mod N)) mod N`

`1 mod N = 0`, so that simplifies to `(((a-2*b) mod N) mod N)`

I don't know that that's "simpler", but shouldn't that work?

Comment: if you consider that to be simpler, then yes it can

Comment: Fair enough. It uses the stated property, but It's definitely no cleaner, and uses the same number of operations.

Comment: @KyleTravis Why is 1 mod N = 0?

Comment: Nevermind, I was thinking `N mod 1` and flipped things when I wrote it down, sorry for the confusion. It seems to me like this couldn't be simplified further then, without some other condition. `1 mod N = 1`, which leaves you with only an additional `mod`.